# Google App Engine + Django with multiple apps within project = ImportError

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I'm trying to get a "Hello World" Django 1.5 app working with Google App Engine. Everything works **perfectly** if my directory structure is like this:

```
.
| ____myproj
| |______init__.py
| |____app.yaml
| |____settings.py
| |____urls.py
| |____views.py
| |____wsgi.py
|____manage.py
```

However, as soon as I add a new "app" to the project (using `manage.py startapp app1`), I start getting ImportErrors.

This is the ideal structure I want:

```
.
|____app1
| |______init__.py
| |____admin.py
| |____models.py
| |____tests.py
| |____views.py
|____myproj
| |______init__.py
| |____app.yaml
| |____settings.py
| |____urls.py
| |____views.py
| |____wsgi.py
|____manage.py
```

To enable "app1", I modify the INSTALLED_APPS in my settings.py to:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app1',
)
```

Notice I added "app1" to INSTALLED_APPS. As soon as I do that, GAE starts complaining:
**ImportError: No module named app1**.

What am I doing wrong? If I try to run the app with pure Django (not AppEngine), everything is fine. But if I try to run it with AppEngine, it doesn't like that "app1" I added to my INSTALLED_APPS. Removing that line from INSTALLED_APPS makes everything run again with no errors in AppEngine!

Note: my PYTHONPATH has '/Users/mel/Sites/myproj/myproj' followed by all the standard google app engine paths.

Answer (score 2):

Solved it myself! This turned out to be a configuration error on my part. When you have a Django project with ***multiple*** apps, the app.yaml file needs to be "outside" the project directory. In other words, the app.yaml file needs to be sitting next to `manage.py` instead of next to `settings.py`. That way, all the apps in your project will automatically get included in the PYTHONPATH.

Note: You may also need to add the following 2 lines to app.yaml:

```
env_variables:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: 'myproj.settings'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not typically how a django project is organized.

Right now, your app is living inside the project. Those should instead be living side by side.

Assuming your project is named `proj` and your app `app`, this is what your directory layer should look like:

```
.
├── manage.py
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   └── views.py
└── proj
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── settings.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── wsgi.py
```

Comment: This is exactly how my directory is organized. I think you misinterpreted the structure in my question.

Comment: @melsam I don't think so. Your app folder is not living next to your `manage.py` file, and is instead living next to your `settings.py` file. If that's not correct, you should fix the indentation in your question (or generate the layout using `tree` so it's clearer).

Comment: @melsa To be clearer: `app1` should be *next*  to `myproject`, not under it.

Comment: I have updated the project structure in the question using the tree command. the question is still open...why is Google App Engine complaining about "app1" in INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: @melsam Can you try and get your `PYTHONPATH` (`sys.path`)?

Comment: My PYTHONPATH has '/Users/mel/Sites/myproj/myproj' followed by all the standard Google App Engine paths.